# Is this function O(N+M) or O(N*M)?

Tags: python, complexity-theory, big-o

```
def solution(M, A):
    result = [0] * M
    maxCount = 0
    setAll = 0

    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        if (A[i] == M + 1):
            setAll += maxCount
            maxCount = 0
            result = [0] * M
        else:
            result[A[i] - 1] += 1

            if (result[A[i] - 1] > maxCount):
                maxCount = result[A[i] - 1]

    for j in range(0,len(result)):
        result[j] += setAll

    return result


A = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3] 
M = 2

print solution(M, A) # result = [ 4, 4 ]


A = [ 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1] 
M = 3

print solution(M, A) # result = [ 4, 2, 2 ]
```

By my count, solution() loops through A N times and then loops result M times thus N+M.
However, an online test said that it was instead N*M, leaving me stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `O(M + N)`; there are no nested loops here. This can be reduced to the cost for the larger number; asymptotically, the smaller loop is not going to matter, making it `O(N)`.

First you loop over `A` elements (`N` iterations), then separately you loop over `M` elements.

Comment: I don't see nested loops... am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the word 'no' was missing. :-P Oops!

Comment: I *do* see a nested loop (kind of): `for i in range(0,len(A)): ... result = [0] * M`. Creating the right hand side of the assignment should be Theta(M), doing this N times is Theta(O*N) (worst case).

Answer (score 5):

It is `O(N)`, because the there are `N + M` loops for a given input `N, M`. That reduces to the larger of the two (let's say that is `N`) for the purposes of time complexity, because we only take the most significant term. It would be `O(N*M)` if the second loop was nested inside the first.